# How to fetch values from each index of a JSON array using the Chainlink HTTP Get request?

Tags: chainlink

I have an api endpoint which gives this JSON array in response .

```
[
{
"contractAddress": "0x33bAe0949E0Bb7df7Cd7d63E6808CFacE42EdbC2",
 ....
},
{
"contractAddress": "0x518E679d48F7f3CF82D51a6cB1f3CfcFbad83Aeb",
 ....
},
{
"contractAddress": "0x71354912666ff3128C36B26834C0cDF6d23fbd30",
 ....
}
]
```

I am using this code to make HTTP Get request to the api and to fetch the contractAddress from the 0th index of this JSON array.

```
 constructor() {
  setChainlinkToken(0x779877A7B0D9E8603169DdbD7836e478b4624789);
  setChainlinkOracle(0x6090149792dAAeE9D1D568c9f9a6F6B46AA29eFD);
  jobId = "7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b";
  fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10;
 }

 function _checkForDomain() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
  Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
   jobId,
   address(this),
   this.fulfill.selector
  );

  req.add("get","https://example.com");
  req.add("path", "0,contractAddress");

  return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
 }

 function fulfill(bytes32 _requestId, string memory _address1) public 
 recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
  response1 = _address1;
 }
```

How can I fetch contractAddress from each index of this JSON array?

Comment: I'll need to double check this, but I think you will need to "know" the array length and then loop it to access every single array object

Comment: @Andrej array length is not constant.

Comment: In that case, you have two options. Option 1) Use Chainlink Functions instead. With Chainlink Functions you can perform a HTTP GET request, arrange the returned array using JavaScript and provide the end result to the calling smart contract. Option 2) A bit of a hacky way. Use an External Adapter to concatenate array elements into the large bytes variable and then use the Large Responses method https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/large-responses